# How to validate a symfony expression language expression

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I'm making a system where users can enter they own expressions.
I've [searched](https://www.symfony.fi/entry/its-time-to-get-creative-with-the-symfony-expression-language) all [of](http://blog.elcodi.io/blog/2014/05/20/about-rules-and-expressionlanguage/) the [internet](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/index.html) and I can't seem to find a sample of how I could validate the user entered expression before executing it.

Is there a "standard way" or "best practice" to **validate user entered expressions** or do I have to roll my own validation?

## EDIT

I just want to allow a user to filter a table (array), so the expressions I guess wouldn't be overly complex.

so for an array with headers like `array('id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'docId', 'profit');` I'm expecting expressions like: `row.id < 2 and row.profit <= 500`

Comment: i depends how complex are your "expressions", simplest cases could be validated using regular expressions, for complex cases you need to build state machine (or use external library). how about you give us some examples ?

Comment: hmm ,so i guess you dont REALLY need processing of complex expressions, so i think in your case better solution is to offer to user more strict client based (javascript) filter where he would select from array(table) columns, operator and value ... (and he could add more of these filters)

Answer (score 3):

The `Symfony/ExpressionLanguage` package have a `SyntaxError` class, and throws this exception if exist error in expression.

Control error:

```
use Symfony\Component\ExpressionLanguage\ExpressionLanguage;
use Symfony\Component\ExpressionLanguage\SyntaxError;

$expressionLanguage = new ExpressionLanguage();

try {
    $expressionLanguage->evaluate('1 + b.foo');
} catch (SyntaxError $e) {
    // Error
}
```

But, we can not control error by types:

1. Invalid syntax
2. Variable not found
3. Unexpected token
4. Function not found
5. etc...

As solution (bad idea), you can control types via text in exception.

Comment: Just a side note: as of Symfony 4.2 the class `SyntaxError` is still there but `RuntimeException` is used / thrown instead.